# Sabre GetReservation wsdl does not contains schema for PriceQuoteServices

Tags: python, xsd, wsdl, sabre, zeep

I am using sabre GetReservation SOAP call its working fine but now I added PRICE_QUOTE subject area which contains response of PriceQuoteServices but the wsdl provided by sabre for GetReservation does not contains xsd(schemas) for PriceQuoteServices. 
The issue is when I am going to parse the xml response of GetReservation using python-zeep it ignores the PRICE_QUOTE object since it was not defined in the schemas. Is their any work around for this instead of geting raw_response from zeep and then converting to json?

Answer (score 1):

This is because there are basically two transactions being merged in the response.  The Price_Quote subject area tells the system to also return the PriceQuoteServicesRQ response as part of the XML.

The documentation for PriceQuoteServicesRQ is on Sabre Dev Studio - the transaction is actually called 'Manage Price Quote Details'

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/fulfill/manage_price_quote_details/resources

There is a WSDL and Docs there for you to use

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, you are right I could use seperate service for getiing price quote object but I am trying to get this in getReservation by using price quote subject area. The issue is that, in xml response of GetReservation I am getting price quote object but when response is parsed through the xsds defined price quote object gets ignored and returned as empty object. I had cloned all the schemas and tried to ignore parsing of price quote object through the schema and I got the result, there might be probably some issue with price quote schema.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use two transactions - as you have both schema, you can manually edit the GetReservation one you've downloaded locally and copy in the relevant section from the PriceQuoteServices one into it !

Comment: @PaulT have you done this editing? Could you please share an example?